# sqlite C API, UDATE database

Tags: c++, sql, database, api, sqlite

I'm Currently working to develop a method of creating an edit window in a program I already have, which accesses an Sqlite database which is set and contains 4 pieces for info, id for the entry, name of the entry(which is user specified), a file location(also user entered) and members of the group. 
In the edit window, there are two labels, a text entry box for the name and a button to open the file browser.
my problem is when I set in the sql database in the add new window, the all the data is set in the database, although when I then want to edit the data from the database, I currently delete the old data then add in new, although looking over the documentation on line I found an UPDATE method, and though this would work better, but can't get the right indexes for the database somehow, how I call for index 3, I get an error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01143622 in bv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

after some research I found that this is caused by a NULL reference pointer, which the only cause I could find for this would be that the field is empty, but I clearly set it in the add window. 
Please Help :(

```
std::string campaign_sql("SELECT id, name, config, members FROM bv_campaigns");

sqlite3_stmt *prepped_statement;
sqlite3_prepare(mainApp->GetAppData().db_conn, campaign_sql.c_str(), campaign_sql.length(), &prepped_statement, NULL);
//std::string name((const char *)sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 1));
while ( SQLITE_ROW == sqlite3_step(prepped_statement) ) 
{
    std::string name((const char *)sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 1));
    wxMessageBox(name);
    std::string config((const char *)sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 3));
    wxMessageBox(config);
```

returns NULL reference error

```
std::string name = pds.getCampaignName();
            std::string config = pds.serialize();

            std::string update_sql("INSERT INTO bv_campaigns (name, type, config) VALUES(?,'campaignCallListDataSourcePython',?)");
            sqlite3_stmt *prepped_statement;
            sqlite3_prepare(this->GetAppData().db_conn, update_sql.c_str(), update_sql.length(), &prepped_statement, NULL);

            sqlite3_bind_text(prepped_statement, 1, name.c_str(), name.length(), NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(prepped_statement, 3, config.c_str(), config.length(), NULL);
```

where data is added, serialize and get campaign name functions get the values from the add window,

I think that's everything needed. If I'm missing anything please ask.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_text(..., 3)` reads the value of the forth `SELECT` column, which is `members`.

This column has not been set by your `INSERT` command, so it is `NULL`.

(Also, in the `INSERT` command, the parameters have indexes 1 and 2; you never set `config` either.)

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't seem to know much about this, this is my first time using sqlite in c++, but now when I try SELECTing index 2 I still get the same NULL error, how would I go about accessing the value INSERTed? thank you for the response :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `SELECT`; the second parameter to `sqlite3_bind_text` should be 1 and 2 for the first and second `?`.

Comment: okay, I think I'm getting there, but if the values is inserted to the config column, why can't I select it from the database? thanks again

Comment: Open the database file with another tool to check whether that column actually contains data.

Comment: umm, how would you recommend I do that? I have a .sdf file, after some googling, I found a few different tolls, but none would work, I tried LINQ and sqlitebrowser. :The database file has been created by an earlier version of SQL Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method. is the error LINQpad was giving, and the browser program was saying it is not a SQL database file :/

Comment: An .sdf file is not an SQLite file. You should know which database file your program is accessing.

Comment: sorry, for the trouble, do you know of any simple tutorials coving this topic? I'm still not having any luck with it, google isn't helping me either. thank you for your time and I will acept your answer as I believe you are correct

Comment: Read something like [The Definitive Guide to SQLite](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430232250). You can [download the examples](http://www.apress.com/9781430232254); maybe they help even without the book.

Comment: now having a much better understanding of this, the Insert statement indexes correspond to the '?'s not the brackets, or the column indexes, which was my mistake, so this answer is correct, I just wanted to clarify for anyone who makes a similar dumb mistake. and again thank ypu to @CL. for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to step your program through in a debugger.  It will show you on which line you access NULL pointer.  There you will be able to figure out how it gets into such state.

Comment: the debug tells me that the error occurs   :- [std::string config((const char *)sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 3));]         but as shown in my code, I have set the third index with the config variable :(

Comment: Looks like call to sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 3) returns a null pointer then.  Re-write this code this way to verify:
const char *ptr = (const char*)sqlite3_column_text(prepped_statement, 3);
std::string config(ptr);

Comment: ptr is probably going to be null before string config gets created.

Comment: Also, you need to re-evaluate you casting here.  Constructor of std::string takes a regular char pointer, not const char pointer.

Comment: @shargors "Constructor of std::string takes a regular char pointer, not const char pointer" ?? since *when*?? From <string>: `basic_string(const _CharT* __s, const _Alloc& __a = _Alloc())`

Comment: Oops, sorry.  What I meant to say was that std::string can be instantiated with a regular pointer.

Comment: @WhoCraig sorry guys but my supervisor wrote the original piece of code, and he is a genius, so I don't believe there is any problems with the constructing of std::string. thanks though xx

Comment: @jbaldwin No, there is no problem.  It's just the code looks unclean with all that unnecessary casting in it.